# Send process to background and disown and exit the terminal (& and && operator clash in zsh)

Tags: zsh, background-process, disown

I need to run a process in the background and then exit the current terminal.

The following command results in error:

```
> google-chrome-stable &! && exit
zsh: parse error near '&&'
```

I've considered simply invoking 'google-chrome-stable &!' and checking the error code via an if statement, but hope to identify a simpler way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

`&!` and `&&` both separate commands, so you can’t combine both, so

```
google-chrome-stable &! exit
```

is probably what you’re after.

You can’t get the exit code until the backgrounded command exits...

Answer (score 1):

The exit status returned to the invoking shell from starting a background job is *always* zero:

```
% bogus &
[1] 66712
% zsh: command not found: bogus

[1]  + exit 127   bogus
% echo $?
0
```

... and both `&!` and `&&` are command terminators.
This means that your command should probably be written as

```
google-chrome-stable &! exit
```

or as the equivalent

```
google-chrome-stable &!
exit
```

You can only get at the real exit status of the background job by using `wait` with the job ID of the job (there is none since you disowned it) or the process ID (but you can't, because you disowned that process and it's therefore no longer a process that the shell considers a child process; it's removed from the shell's list of current jobs).

If you hadn't disowned the job, maybe through

```
google-chrome-stable & chrome_pid=$!
```

then the command `wait $chrome_pid` would eventually exit with the exit status of your background job, but not until that job terminates, either by not being able to start, or by you closing the browser by some means.